# CakePHP: Undefined variable: session

Tags: php, cakephp

I get the following errors on my app:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: session [APP/views/layouts/admin_default.ctp, line 19]
Fatal error: Call to a member function flash() on a non-object in /Users/cameron/Sites/crm/app/views/layouts/admin_default.ctp on line 19
```

Line 19 being: `<?php echo $session->flash(); ?>`

Any ideas what the problem is? I have included the Session component in the AppController so why is it complaining about it?

Cheers

Comment: Can you divide your line into 2 ones, so see what exactly produces error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the Session HELPER! :)

Comment: This means adding `var $helpers = array('Session');` to your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by adding a Session Component in my custom app_controller.php.

My apologizes by my bad english.

Regards.

**code from comment:**

```
if ($this->Book->save($this->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('El álbum fue actualizado.'); 
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index')); 
}
```

Comment: But you should still use the new syntax: `$this->Session->flash()` etc

Comment: Yes I do. This is my code...
                  
`if ($this->Book->save($this->data))
 {
    $this->Session->setFlash('El álbum fue actualizado.');
                
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}`
                  
Do you need used another way to show a Flash message?

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('tu mensaje'); ?>
```